# Invalid username/password when accessing Keycloak's H2 database

Tags: h2, keycloak

I am attempting to follow the guide [here](https://thrysoee.dk/keycloak-h2/) to view my H2 database directly.

When executing the command: `java -cp $jar org.h2.tools.Console -url "$url" -user sa -password sa`

I get the following exception `Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-193]`

This seems relatively straightforward, but I cannot seem to figure out my credentials. I am running keycloak 7.0.0 locally through a docker image and I have not knowingly modified anything about the database. So far I have tried permutations of sa, empty, and my keycloak credentials with no success.

Is there any way to get/set/create a set of credentials for this database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the default password for an off-the-shelf h2 database is "" (empty).

Nevertheless you can also find or configure your datasource from [the subsystem configuration files](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#manage-subsystem-configuration).

You should find something like this.

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
     <datasources>
       ​<drivers>
         ​<driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
           ​<xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
         ​</driver>
       ​</drivers>
       ...
       <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
           <driver>h2</driver>
           <connection-url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</connection-url>
           <security>
               <user-name>sa</user-name>
               <password>?</password>
           </security>
       </datasource>
        ...
     </datasources>
```

Keycloak rely on Widlfly, [which documentation gives more info about database configuration](http://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#DataSource).

Answer (score 1):

in Keycloak 23

- username: **sa**
- password: **password**